# python log stderr to file

Tags: python, debian

i am trying to create a backup script using ssh and called the subprocess.Popen module, next it checks if
stderr contains anything and writes the error to log file, but it detects the first output to be part of stderr

```
def server():
    bpath = "/mnt/backup/server-address/usrlocalbin/"
    rpath = "/usr/local/bin"
    bpath1 = "/mnt/backup/server-address/project/"
    rpath1 = "/var/www/project"
    cmd1 = "ssh -q root@server-address tar -zcf - "+rpath+" > " +bpath+"usrlocalbin.tar.gz"
    cmd2 = "ssh -q root@server-address tar -zcf - "+rpath1+" > " +bpath1+"project.tar.gz"
    exec1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout,stderr = exec1.communicate()
    if stderr:
        log.write(t+ " "+ stderr + " \n")
    else:
        log.write(t+ " "+ "Backup of /usr/local/bin/ for server-address complete..\n")
    exec2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout,stderr = exec2.communicate()
    if stderr:
        log.write(t+ " "+ stderr + " \n")
    else:
        log.write(t+ " "+ "Backup of /var/www/project for server-address complete..\n")
```

on the log file

```
15-September-2011_12.14PM tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

i think it picked up the first line and thought it as part of stderr... any ideas how to fix this?

**after more research:**

it was because of tar...

fixed using

"ssh -q root@cce-linsvcs-001 tar zcfP - "+rpath+" > " +bpath+"usrlocalbin.tar.gz"

**new error**

to test the stderr again, i disabled ssh to the remote host

```
ssh root@server-address
ssh: connect to host server-address port 22: No route to host
```

and stderr did not catch this error? any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

No, the verbose flag prints the file list to the stderr and it couldn't be otherwise because in the stdout is wrote the tar file. What you can do is do not use the verbose flag.

ps. for this small scripts I think shell scripts are more efficient.

Comment: cool, forgot to take the v flag out..now it gives this error "15-September-2011_12.48PM tar: Removing leading `/' from member names"

Comment: a two seconds reading of the tar man page I found the `-P` flag, look if that is what you need, or you can write a filter that strip that exactly string or just the first line. again, a shell script is more appropriate.

Comment: i already used the P flag, and it cannot catch the ssh error, i want to accomplish  this in python, i know in bash its straightforward..

Comment: don't modify massively your questions or the answers could become meaningless, at least just append at the end. I just tried the command and works, check again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `-n` flag to the SSH command.
If `tar` sees a `stdin` input, it will send the error to `stdout` instead of `stderr`:
"Removing leading `/' from member names"

Disabling `stdin` with the ssh client (`-n`) will cause `tar` to use `stderr` for reporting.